# Flutter Scaffold, Actions and End Drawer together?

Tags: flutter

In Scaffold if 'actions' parameter is used it hides the 'endDrawer'. Is it possible to display both?

```
var tmp = new Scaffold(
  /// end drawer
    endDrawer: Container(color: Colors.red,
        child: Text('END DRAWER')),
    appBar: new AppBar(
        title: Text('Title'),
    actions: <Widget>[

      /// Cancel, Save
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
        child: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.clear,size: 24.0,),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context), //cancelButton,
        ),
      ),
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
        child: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.check_circle,size: 30.0,),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
        ),)
    ],
),
    body: new Container(color: Colors.amber,);
```

Comment: Please paste the code snippet of the work you're trying to do.

Comment: check this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53952989/duplicate-globalkey-with-custom-scaffold-in-flutter

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem. I only used a tricky solution to solve this do the following:

**1.**

```
class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  
  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>(); `

here we add (final _scaffoldKey). inside the class.
```

**2.**

```
return Scaffold(
  key: _scaffoldKey
```

here inside the scaffold assign the variable to the key

**3.** Add the first icon button to be icon.menu, when the icon pressed it will show the end drawer as shown bellow:

```
IconButton(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.menu,color: Colors.white),
          onPressed: () {
            _scaffoldKey.currentState.openEndDrawer();
          },
        ),
```

**AND**

```
  class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  
    final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        appBar: AppBar(
          actions: [
            return IconButton(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.menu, color: Colors.white),
            onPressed: () {
              _scaffoldKey.currentState.openEndDrawer();
            });
          ]
        ),
      );
    }
```

Comment: Where do I add the IconButton? Tried adding it to leading: , actions[ ] but do not get the function .openEndDrawer() for _scaffoldKey.currentState

Comment: You need to specifically declare the type as follows:
final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

Comment: @AntD it's explained below in the code :)

Answer (score 0):

Extend the Scaffold class

```
class CustomScaffoldWidget extends Scaffold {
  CustomScaffoldWidget({
    AppBar appBar,
    Widget body,
    GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> key,
    Widget endDrawer,
    Widget drawer,
    FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton,
    FloatingActionButtonLocation floatingActionButtonLocation,
    FloatingActionButtonAnimator floatingActionButtonAnimator,
    List<Widget> persistentFooterButtons,
    Color backgroundColor,
    Widget bottomSheet,
    Widget bottomNavigationBar,
    bool resizeToAvoidBottomPadding = true,
    bool primary = true,
  })  : assert(key != null),
        super(
          key: key,
          appBar: endDrawer != null &&
                  appBar.actions != null &&
                  appBar.actions.isNotEmpty
              ? _buildEndDrawerButton(appBar, key)
              : appBar,
          body: body,
          floatingActionButton: floatingActionButton,
          floatingActionButtonLocation: floatingActionButtonLocation,
          floatingActionButtonAnimator: floatingActionButtonAnimator,
          persistentFooterButtons: persistentFooterButtons,
          drawer: drawer,
          endDrawer: endDrawer,
          bottomNavigationBar: bottomNavigationBar,
          bottomSheet: bottomSheet,
          backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
          resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: resizeToAvoidBottomPadding,
          primary: primary,
        );

  static AppBar _buildEndDrawerButton(
      AppBar myAppBar, GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _keyScaffold) {
    myAppBar.actions.add(IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
        onPressed: () => !_keyScaffold.currentState.isEndDrawerOpen
            ? _keyScaffold.currentState.openEndDrawer()
            : null));
    return myAppBar;
  }
}
```

Replace your current Scaffold with the extended one. The global key will ensure you do not get a duplicate key exception error on other pages. However, the assertion in the constructor will notify you if you dont provide a key.

```
class HomeView extends StatelessWidget {
GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _key = GlobalKey();
Widget build(BuildContext context){
return CustomScaffoldWidget(
key:_key,
endDrawer:Drawer(),
appBar: AppBar(actions:[Icon(Icons.search),]),
body: Center(child: Text('custom Scaffold'))
);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I suggest creating a custom Scaffold by just copy-paste the below code and use MyCustomScaffold instead of Scaffold.

```
class MyCustomScaffold extends Scaffold {
  static GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _keyScaffold = GlobalKey();
  MyCustomScaffold({
    AppBar appBar,
    Widget body,
    Widget floatingActionButton,
    FloatingActionButtonLocation floatingActionButtonLocation,
    FloatingActionButtonAnimator floatingActionButtonAnimator,
    List<Widget> persistentFooterButtons,
    Widget drawer,
    Widget endDrawer,
    Widget bottomNavigationBar,
    Widget bottomSheet,
    Color backgroundColor,
    bool resizeToAvoidBottomPadding = true,
    bool primary = true,
  }) : super(
          key: _keyScaffold,
          appBar: endDrawer != null &&
                  appBar.actions != null &&
                  appBar.actions.isNotEmpty
              ? _buildEndDrawerButton(appBar)
              : appBar,
          body: body,
          floatingActionButton: floatingActionButton,
          floatingActionButtonLocation: floatingActionButtonLocation,
          floatingActionButtonAnimator: floatingActionButtonAnimator,
          persistentFooterButtons: persistentFooterButtons,
          drawer: drawer,
          endDrawer: endDrawer,
          bottomNavigationBar: bottomNavigationBar,
          bottomSheet: bottomSheet,
          backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
          resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: resizeToAvoidBottomPadding,
          primary: primary,
        );

  static AppBar _buildEndDrawerButton(AppBar myAppBar) {
    myAppBar.actions.add(IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
        onPressed: () => !_keyScaffold.currentState.isEndDrawerOpen
            ? _keyScaffold.currentState.openEndDrawer()
            : null));
    return myAppBar;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an easier way. for the title, create a Row and add a Text, spacer and Icons. In my case I wanted the title on the left side and the icons on the right next to the end drawer.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        endDrawer: Drawer(
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 2,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(Icons.list),
                    title: Text("GFG item $index"),
                    trailing: Icon(Icons.done),
                  );
                })),
        appBar: AppBar(
            title: Row(
          children: [
            Text(
              "App title",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            Spacer(),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
              onPressed: () {},
              color: Colors.white,
            )
          ],
        )),
        body: _showBody());
  }
```